# Redistributable local database for windows desktop app

Tags: sql-server

I am getting a little bit confused about the difference of the followings:

1. SQL Server Express
2. SQL Server Compact
3. localDB

My requirement is to develop a desktop application that will use basic RDBMS features. I need to package the application and allow the user to install a single distributed package. I don't want the user to install even SQL server express.

In this case, which DB I should use? SQLite is not considered as too much re-coding has to be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Express is full featured DBMS, with some limitations in terms of database size and resources it is allowed to use. You can see it's limitations (relative to SQL Server) [on microsofts site (Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

SQL Server CE is embedded database, meaning that it runs in user mode, it's easy to deploy (requires you to copy just few assemblies), lightweight but fast, can be run by a low privileged user. It's supported by NHibernate. However, has more limitations. To me most notable is that there are problems when you try to have multiple connections to same database. Although MS claims that this is supported, if you try this in Windows 2008 server, you will fail. And what's worse, such use scenario may lead to DB corruption. This means that you will effectively not be able to use some Management tool to update data while your service/website is running. Also, SQL Server Management studio doesn't support SQL CE anymore, so you will have to use a 3rd party tool, like Database.NET. It also does not support subqueries.

localDB, having not used it, sounds like a compromise. It's a standalone database which is executed in user mode (can be used by low privilege user), but must be installed so you will need administrative privileges for that part. Offers set of capabilities of SQL Server Express. It's much larger than SQL CE, and also requires to be installed (unlike CE which is just binary drop in). Shortest overview of this DBMS [can be found here.](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0004.htm)

Comment: Hi, I wish to compile my app with the DB engine, and user don't have to install any SQL server. Is SQL Server CE only for mobile device?

Comment: No, SQL Server CE can be used with desktop applications. You do not have to install it, you just place it's assembly in your application directory, and create a database file (a .sdf file).

Comment: I don't see that SQL CE is easy to deploy to machines that don't already have VS and the necessary .NET Framework. Maybe it was intended to be easy, but it is not a trivial task to deploy it on different machine configurations.

Comment: Can you provide some information about that so that I have it for future reference? For me, copying a DLL is easier than going through setup wizard of SQL Server and settings up user accounts and permissions.